# A Spring Network Encircled with a Loop

Tags: tikz-pgf

Thanks to @marmot I have drawn a square lattice of springs in TikZ. See the code appended.  However, I would like to encircle that lattice with a polygon of a coloured background (in light-gray let's say) beyond which the network is no longer extended. A similar example is given in the photo. Thank you for the help in advance.

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-1,-1) rectangle (11,11);
\foreach \X in {-2,0,...,10}
{\foreach \Y in {-2,0,...,10}
{\draw[decorate,decoration={coil,aspect=0.5,amplitude=1.5mm, segment length=1.5mm}] (\X,\Y) -- ++(0,2) -- ++(2,0);
\node[circle,inner color=black,outer color=white] at (\X,\Y) {$\bullet$};}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray,decorate,decoration={coil,aspect=0,segment length=4.5mm}] 
plot[smooth cycle,tension=0.3] coordinates {(-0.75,-0.75) (10.75,-0.75)
 (10.75,10.75) (-0.75,10.75)};
\clip decorate [decoration={coil,aspect=0,segment length=4.5mm}] 
{plot[smooth cycle,tension=0.3] coordinates {(-0.75,-0.75) (10.75,-0.75)
 (10.75,10.75) (-0.75,10.75)}};
\foreach \X in {-2,0,...,10}
{\foreach \Y in {-2,0,...,10}
{\draw[decorate,decoration={coil,aspect=0.5,amplitude=1.5mm, segment length=1.5mm}] (\X,\Y) -- ++(0,2) -- ++(2,0);
\node[circle,inner color=black,outer color=white] at (\X,\Y) {$\bullet$};}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or without wiggles.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray] 
plot[smooth cycle,tension=0.3] coordinates {(-0.75,-0.75) (10.75,-0.75)
 (10.75,10.75) (-0.75,10.75)};
\clip plot[smooth cycle,tension=0.3] coordinates {(-0.75,-0.75) (10.75,-0.75)
 (10.75,10.75) (-0.75,10.75)};
\foreach \X in {-2,0,...,10}
{\foreach \Y in {-2,0,...,10}
{\draw[decorate,decoration={coil,aspect=0.5,amplitude=1.5mm, segment length=1.5mm}] (\X,\Y) -- ++(0,2) -- ++(2,0);
\node[circle,inner color=black,outer color=white] at (\X,\Y) {$\bullet$};}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]